# You did not set a valid publishable key. call stripe.setpublishablekey() with your publishable key after cleared cache in laravel

Tags: stripe-payments

I have big problem now. I developed website using the Laravel framework. Also, I integrated Stripe payment gateway, but when I make a payment, it says that you did not set a valid publishable key. call stripe.setpublishablekey() with your publishable key. So I did operate PHP artisan cache:clear and PHP artisan config:clear, but same as before. I don't understand why it happens.
If anyone knew this issue, please let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You also want to run `php artisan config:cache` after clearing the cached configuration. What you'll need to do after that, however, is examine `bootstrap/config/cache.php` to see if your Stripe publishable key is set as expected in the configuration. In your production environment, you need to also ensure that all required environment variables are set—this might be something you need to configure in your hosting control panel, nginx / application server settings, etc.

Be sure also that you **always** use `env()` to access your configuration variables, otherwise [`config:cache` will not work](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/configuration#configuration-caching).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yeah I reviewed the cache.php file as you mentioned. I solved this issue using "php artisan view:clear" command. But I like your reply.